# Is there any better controls then MS chart controls

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, charts, mschart

Currently i am using Microsoft charting controls to show reports in my website. but i am fed of them as these controls are not interactive and very heavy to load. I have used SSRS but didn't not find it user friendly. is there any better alternative and free to use. please suggest.

Comment: This is the classic "opinion based" question. What about using Google to see what there is on the market and then come back with specific questions?

Comment: as i searched in google but there are a lot of paid tools out there. i am specifically looking for tools that are free to use and are interactive and robust. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zed-graph and best interactive chart control is google api u can refer this link `https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery` and you can refer `http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/tag/charts/`